# Hartshorne book Proposition (II.5.13)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Hartshorne book Proposition (II.5.13) is that

Let $A$ be a ring ,let $S=A[x_0,\cdots,x_r]$ and let $X={\rm Proj}S$.
Then, $\Gamma_*(\mathcal{O}_X) \cong S$.

In proof,
To give a setion $t \in \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X(n))$ is the same as giving sections $t_i \in \mathcal{O}_X(n)(D_+(x_i))$ for each $i$ which agrees on the intersection $D_+(x_ix_j)$.

I don't know meaning of following statement:

Summing over all $n$, we see that $\Gamma(\mathcal(O)_X$ can be identified with the set $(r+1)$-tuples $(t_0,\cdots,t_r)$ where for each $i$, $t_i\in S_{x_i}$, and for each $i,j$, the image of $t_i$ and $t_j$ in $S_{x_ix_j}$ are the same.\

Help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To give a global section of  $X$ it suffices to give compatible sections (i.e. same restriction) over an open cover of $X$. Now take the open cover $\{D_+(x_i)\}$. Each $D_+ (x_i)$ is affine with global sections $S_{x_i}$, so the $(r+1)$-tuple correspond to a collection of sections one over each $D_+(x_i)$. The intersection of $D_+(x_i)$ and $D_+(x_j)$ is $D_+(x_ix_j) = Spec S_{x_ix_j}$, so the compatibility condition of sections translate to the image of $t_i$ and $t_j$ agree in $S_{x_ix_j}$.